# R dividing all elements on the same row

Tags: r, dataframe

Hello i have a dataFrame with 15167 rows like this:

```
   > head(datExpr)
                F02234_L1_S1_L001 F02235_L1_S2_L001
ENSG00000182199              1546              1710
ENSG00000157870              3491              2951
ENSG00000077092                35                22
ENSG00000047936                49                12
ENSG00000156282                 0                 0
ENSG00000183856               265               365
                F02236_L1_S3_L001 F02237_L1_S4_L001
ENSG00000182199              3530              3582
ENSG00000157870              2372              2360
ENSG00000077092               111                34
ENSG00000047936                43                 6
ENSG00000156282                 0                 0
ENSG00000183856               768              1489
```

and a list with 15167 elements like this:

```
    > distances
[[1]]
      end_position
1            12883
2           100722
3           119629
4            57174
5            78317
6           453372
7            21772
8            30102
9           116734
```

..........

I want to divide all in the dataframe by equivalent values of my list. For example 1546/12883,1710/12883, 3530/12883 ... and 3491/100722, 2951/100722...

How can i do that with R?

Comment: Can you show the `length(distances)`?  Is it a list of length 1?

Comment: yes the length of "distance" is 1. actually it was a str, i made it list with 

distance=list(distance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could directly divide the list element after extracting as it gets recycled

```
datExpr/distances[[1]]$end_position
```

-output

```
            F02234_L1_S1_L001 F02235_L1_S2_L001 F02236_L1_S3_L001 F02237_L1_S4_L001
ENSG00000182199      0.1200031049      0.1327330591      0.2740045021      0.2780408290
ENSG00000157870      0.0346597566      0.0292984651      0.0235499692      0.0234308294
ENSG00000077092      0.0002925712      0.0001839019      0.0009278687      0.0002842120
ENSG00000047936      0.0008570329      0.0002098856      0.0007520901      0.0001049428
ENSG00000156282      0.0000000000      0.0000000000      0.0000000000      0.0000000000
ENSG00000183856      0.0005845090      0.0008050784      0.0016939732      0.0032842787
```

#### data

```
datExpr <- structure(list(F02234_L1_S1_L001 = c(1546L, 3491L, 35L, 49L, 
0L, 265L), F02235_L1_S2_L001 = c(1710L, 2951L, 22L, 12L, 0L, 
365L), F02236_L1_S3_L001 = c(3530L, 2372L, 111L, 43L, 0L, 768L
), F02237_L1_S4_L001 = c(3582L, 2360L, 34L, 6L, 0L, 1489L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("ENSG00000182199", 
"ENSG00000157870", "ENSG00000077092", "ENSG00000047936", "ENSG00000156282", 
"ENSG00000183856"))

distances <- list(structure(list(end_position = c(12883L, 100722L, 119629L, 
57174L, 78317L, 453372L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6")))
```